# Clang based on platform in CMake

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, cmake, clang

I'm setting up a cross platform build environment. For that reason I've chosen to go for clang, for the, correct me if I'm wrong reasons:

- Using the "same" compiler for different platform would potentially reduce the quirks that arise when getting gcc code to work with MSVC
- Clang with its MSVC compatible ABI would let me work with the WINAPI as if I were using MSVC.

My question is: How do I get CMake to, based on the platform, find the correct clang to use, that is **clang-cl** in Windows and **clang** on *nix platforms ?

Please note that I'll be using Ninja generator for CMake, and the project is Qt based, if that matters.

Comment: `clang-cl.exe` == `clang.exe --driver-mode=cl`. So you could add something to your `CMakeLists.txt` to add the driver-mode option on windows based platforms. Which version(s) of CMake do you use/support with your project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You (the project author) don't get to choose the compiler, the user that invokes CMake chooses the compiler.

The only thing you can do from within the `CMakeLists` is abort with an error if you are not happy with the choice that the user made.

There are a couple of ways how the user can specify to CMake which compiler to use. Popular examples include setting the [respective environment variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/envvar/CXX.html), passing it via [`-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html) on the first CMake run (and *only* on the first run; you cannot change this later without re-configuring from scratch!), or by using a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html).

On Visual Studio, you can also use [the `-T` option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/cmake.1.html#options) to select a build toolchain. This allows you to build with clang from Visual Studio.

You should document in your project's Readme which compiler you expect your users to configure for CMake and maybe give them a small example how to do this via one of the methods above.

Comment: Toolchains seen to be what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot !